# Regarding sleep state of a java thread

Tags: java

sleep function in thread class is static.i read sleep function can make a thread sleep for a particular time while others threads running.

As sleep function is static ...when it is called it will be applicable to all threads.how it will be used to keep particular thread in sleep state.

Comment: Do you *really* want to make a thread other than the current thread sleep?  It's technically possible (but almost never a good idea.)

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread.sleep();
```

will put current thread from which this code is executed in sleep mode

> Causes the ***currently executing thread*** to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds.

- [Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Answer (score 1):

The sleep method is not applicable to all threads, when called it obtains the current thread inside it (probably using another static method, Thread.currentThread()). The method call invocation is only applicable to the current thread due to the principles of heap/stack visibility, and doesn't modify any static fields (it is self-contained).

Answer (score 0):

When called, it will make the currently executing thread sleep.

Answer (score 0):

According to the java documentation :

```
 public static void sleep(long millis,
                             int nanos)
                      throws InterruptedException
```

Causes the **currently executing thread** to sleep (cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds plus the specified number of nanoseconds. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.

So when you call `sleep()`, you will sleep the current thread.

Comment: This `sleep(millis)` is perhaps a better example as the `nanos` is pointless IMHO. i.e. it doesn't do what it suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Since the method depends on the state of the <strike>jvm</strike> calling thread and not on the thread represented by an object it has to be static, anything else would be misleading.

Implementing it to work on Thread instances would not work out well, since stopping other threads can cause the complete jvm to halt if locks to jvm resources are held ([link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)).

Comment: -1 misleading. The "currently running thread" is **not** a global variable (else how could a VM use multiple cores?)